Problem with assigning variables in a for-loop with lares:: corr_var function
I want to test the first columns of a data frame for correlation with their last columns. I'm implementing this to a bigger function, so I never know the variable names. Therefore I need an automated solution, which I'm not able to find. I tried the following:
library(lares)

data("iris")

corlist <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
  corlist[i] <- corr_var(df = iris,
                         var = names(iris)[i],
                         ignore = names(iris)[c(1:2, 5)[-i]],
                         max_pvalue = 0.05,
                         top = 50)
}

Which returns:
Error in corr_var(df = iris, var = names(iris)[i], ignore = names(iris)[c(1:2)[-i]],  : 
  Not a valid input: names(iris)[i] was transformed or does not exist.

I tried using get(), paste(), or noquote(), but neither worked. I also tried to insert the column itself like iris[, i], but I always receive the same error. The only thing that seems to work is e.g. var = Sepal.Length and so on, but these can't be looped. \

This looks like a package bug, the following simple example also fails: corr_var(iris[-c(1, 5)], var = "Sepal.Length"). Try contacting maintainer("lares").

@RuiBarradas, I cannot follow your example as "Sepal.Length" is not part of iris[-c(1, 5)]. Does not really matter, I also think there is bug.

@Friede For what I understand "Sepal.Length" shouldn't be part of iris[-c(1, 5)]. In the posted code the OP removes the ith variable.

@Friede lares::corr_var(df = iris, var = "Sepal.Length", ignore = names(iris)[c(1:2, 5)[-1]], max_pvalue = 0.05, top = 50) this doesn't work either. But then this does work: lares::corr_var(df = iris, var = Sepal.Length, ignore = names(iris)[c(1:2, 5)[-1]], max_pvalue = 0.05, top = 50)

@RuiBarradas I think it's due to this (these) line(s): https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares/blob/main/R/correlations.R#L191

@M--, right. Just variable names written explicitly (outside of iterations) seem to work. From help file "var Variable. Name of the variable to correlate. [...]". Note that lares::corr_var(df = iris, var = noquote("Sepal.Length"), ignore = names(iris)[c(1:2, 5)[-1]], max_pvalue = 0.05, top = 50) does again not work.

Hello. I'm the maintainer of the "lares" package. I'd be happy to approve submitted PRs improving this parameter so that users can pass strings as valid column names and @joran will be able to run his loop as expected. I am also able to replicate the issue only when running in a loop.

@Bernardo fyi I'm not the author of the question, I merely edited it.

While we wait for an update on lares::corr_var(), this should work for you:
corlist <- list()
for(i in 1:2) {
  var_name <- names(iris)[i]
  var_sym <- rlang::sym(var_name)  # Construct symbol from string
  corlist[[i]] <- corr_var(
    df = iris,
    var = !!var_sym,  # Unquote and evaluate symbol
    ignore = names(iris)[c(1:2, 5)[-i]],
    max_pvalue = 0.05,
    top = 50
  )
}


@alexander-klug you can update lares to latest dev version and your original loop should work now as expected. I'll run with formats: var, "var", .data$var
